# What is the complexity of running a loop twice of the same input array?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I am new to Algorithms, and very much interested in learning and implementing them.
Learning them through all available online materials i can find.
I am a little confused regarding this -

Consider this code -

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) { ..... }
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) { ..... }
```

What will be the complexity of this ?
O(n) or O(n^2) ?

Comment: Suppose the running time of the first loop was `n = 5` units. What do you expect the total running time to be, 10 units (`2*n`) or 25 units (`n^2`)?

Comment: Generally, I've always thought of it as nested loops you multiply and consecutive loops you add. Constants drop out of the final complexity

Comment: `O( n * worst_runtime_of_both{......})`

Answer (score 10):

Assuming that the `{ . . . }` is constant time, then the complexity of one loop is O(n).

What is the complexity of two "adjacent" loops?  It is O(n) + O(n).  Or you could think of this as O(n + n) --> O(2n).  Constants drop out of complexity, so this is O(n).

It is an entirely different matter with nested loops.  So the following:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) { ..... }
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) { ..... }
```

would be O(n^2).

Comment: As you mentioned "Constants drop out of complexity" means only if Constant is less than n value? Because if n = 5, then On^2 = 25 as well as O(5n) also 25?

Comment: @mrg . . . You are missing something.  `n` doesn't have a value.  It varies up to infinity.  Hence, a constant is *always* less than `n`.  Constants are constant.  Complexity is based on what happens in the limit as n --> infinity.

Answer (score 3):

The complexity will remain O(n)

(Assuming that you don't have another loop inside those for loops).

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind calculating time complexity is how many time your loop/function is executing each step inside of it ? 
for example: `for` loop

```
for ( int i=0; i < n; i++ ) {
    cout << "hello" << endl;
}
```

the code in curly braces will print `n` times `hello` so the time complexity of this for loop will be `O(n)`

```
for ( int i=0; i < n; i++ ) {
    cout << "hello" << endl;
}
for ( int i=0; i < n; i++ ) {
    cout << "hello" << endl;
}
```

this will print `hello` 2 time more than the previous as it have two for loop. time complexity is O(2n). We ignore the constants while computing time complexity so the time complexity will be `O(n)`

```
for ( int i=0; i < n; i++ ) {
    for ( int j=0; j < n; j++ ) {
        cout << "hello" << endl;
    }
}
```

this will print `hello` `n^2`  time, why ? because for each outer `for loop (i)` you execute inner `for loop(j)` `O(n)` time. so `O(n^2)`will be time complexity

read further http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-of-algorithms-set-4-analysis-of-loops/